# List of calendar methods Google API ruby client

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

This is my code:

```
@token = @auth["credentials"]["token"]
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.access_token = @token
service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
@result = client.execute(
  :api_method => service.calendar_list.list,
  :parameters => {},
  :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

My question is: Where can I find a list of **:api_method** for Google calendar API?

Answer (score 3):

You have the entire reference in this page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/?hl=pt-PT

If you want, for example, to list calendars, you click on the *list* method under *CalendarList* section. There you will find some explanation, arguments, responses and code samples for ruby.

Answer (score 1):

FOR THE RUBY CLIENT, THATS ACTUALLY AT THIS ADDRESS: 
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/CalendarV3/

I had the same problem when I was looking for more information about the api 
methods. Google seems to only bring up their docs and not the ruby 
specific ones.